# Can javascript's 'setInterval' be configured to trigger immediately, and with an interval?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I want to trigger an event regularly I use something like (coffeescript):

```
setInterval (() => myFunction()), 300000
```

But often I want myFunction called immediately, AND regular intervals thereafter.  At present I do this by calling both setTimeout and setInterval, e.g.,

```
setTimeout (() => myFunction()), 0
setInterval (() => myFunction()), 300000
```

or

```
myFunction()
setInterval (() => myFunction()), 300000
```

Can setInterval be used to do this in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom version of `setInterval()` that calls the specified function once at the start and then at intervals.

```
// custom version
window.setIntervalCustom = function(_callback, _delay) {
    _callback(); // call once
    return window.setInterval(_callback, _delay); // at intervals
};

// this will print 1 once at the start and then at intervals of 1000ms
setIntervalCustom(function() { console.log('1'); }, 1000);
```

**Note:** The custom function has been renamed above to avoid any conflict issues with other libs/code thiat might be using the original `setInterval()`

Comment: When monkey patching standard functions you should rather add a new optional parameter to avoid conflicts with other libraries.

Comment: @TimWolla - Yes. That makes sense. But setInterval allows a random set of args after the second (delay) argument. So that might be a little tricky as other libs/code might be using those args and we might misinterpret it..

Answer (score 2):

If your function is able to return itself, then yes.

```
function myFunction() {
    // do some work

    return myFunction;
}

setInterval(myFunction(), 300000);
```

I'll let you translate to CS.

So now you're invoking the function instead of passing it to `setInterval()`. The function runs, and returns itself, which is received by `setInterval()` and invoked as you'd expect.

---

I don't know CS, but it looks like you may be passing an anonymous function that invokes your function.

If so, I'm not sure why you're doing that, but it does guarantee that you can take this approach since you don't need to care about the return value of the original.

```
function myFunction() {
    // do some work
}

setInterval(function() {
    myFunction();

    return myFunction;
}(), 300000);
```

---

If there's more work to do in the anonymous function that should run at every interval, then give the function a name and change `return myFunction;` to `return callback;`.

```
function myFunction() {
    // do some work
}

setInterval(function callback() {
    myFunction();

    // some other work

    return callback;
}(), 300000);
```

Comment: "I don't know CS, but it looks like you may be passing an anonymous function that invokes your function.". Yes, the arrows (`->`, `=>`) create a function.

Comment: @TimWolla: Thanks. That was my suspicion. I would imagine OP would want to do `setInterval myFunction, 300000` or whatever the correct syntax would be.

Comment: The reason probably is that the fat arrow `=>` properly binds `this` to the current scope. You can easily check by yourself on CoffeeScript.org using Try CoffeeScript.

Comment: Is there a typo in the above middle suggestion? I only ask because for some reason js2coffee.org cannot translate it back and forth without error.  This could well be a limitation of CoffeeScript, but just checking...

Comment: @ProfNimrod: No, there's not a typo. It should be an anonymous function that is immediately invoked, which invokes and then returns `myFunction;`